# Magento 2.1: Display enabled paypal express checkout buttons in phtml file?

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, payment-methods

I need to add direct paypal express checkout buttons of enable payment methods in phtml file. I want to use them under custom layout section on cart page.

Answer (score 2):

We can show paypal buttons in phtml file using call createBlock() as following:-

1] For show default paypal button

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Paypal\Block\Express\Shortcut')->setTemplate('express/shortcut.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

2] For show in-context smart paypal button

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Paypal\Block\Express\InContext\Minicart\SmartButton')->setTemplate('express/in-context/shortcut/button.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am answering, How I get resolved this issue?

I created a link in `.phtml` file for Paypal Express:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
$paypalexpress = $baseurl.'paypal/express/start/button/1/';
```

```
<div id="button">
    <a href="<?php echo $paypalexpress; ?>">
    <img id="btnPayPal" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
    </a>
</div>
```